# pynput not importing even though it is installed

Tags: python, pynput, keylogger

I am having issues with importing pynput in a keylogger I am writing(i am learning ethical hacking) it comes up with this error:

```text
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'pynput'
  File "C:\Code_Projects\Key_Log\K_Log.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pynput import keyboard
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling pynput but there still is a error can yoU hep me?

Comment: It is entirely possible you have multiple Pythons installed.  How did you install pynput?  Do you have both Python 2 and Python 3?  Did you use the correct `pip` command?

Comment: check versions for `pip -V` and `python -V` - maybe you have two Pythons installed and `pip` install module for one Python but you run code with other Python. You can use `python -m pip install ...` to make sure you install it for correct Python

Comment: I figured it out that visual studio code was conflicting with my pre installed python!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you installed it correctly? I had a similar problem. In my cmd I executed `pip install pynput` and this worked for me. If this doesn't work check your directory if it's imported correctly and in the correct directory.

Comment: or even you can show using pip command like..  [pip list]